# How to use lists function while using where not in array filter?

Tags: laravel-5

Is it possible to generate a list(for a select item) while using hte whereNotIn filter option.
I tried:

```
$sizes =  Size::lists('name', 'id')->whereNotIn('id', [1,3])->get();;
```

But i get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Collection::whereNotIn()
```

How should i filter these lists options?

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the order of your method calls:

```
$sizes = Size::whereNotIn('id', [1,3])->lists('name', 'id');
```